# Proper way of handling and preventing deadlocks

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've understood that deadlocks occur when an sql query tries to lock an already locked row and I'm currently experiencing deadlocks. here's my sql query below:

`INSERT INTO transactions (product_id, category, C, amount, date)
SELECT 'SomeProduct', 'SomeCategory', v.username, 10, '2016-3-31' FROM balance v 
WHERE v.username = 'SomeUsername' AND v.balance + 10 >= 0`

`balance` is a virtual table that sums transactions to get user's balance.

This error usually is noticed when having a reasonable amount of users which makes it hard to test, any tips on how to avoid deadlocks or any possible solution because I'm inserting rows into the transaction table in a very numerous way and looking to solve it!

I've also tried tried to catch the exception, but I couldn't create a loop that would redo the query until it is finished.

Comment: can you show us the EXPLAIN of the SELECT part. I am nearly sure that v.balance + 10 >= 0 is not the Best way. It will be give a FULL TABLE SCAN. MySQL must calculate each ROW +5 before it can compare. Better ii : v.balance  >= -10. Then they can use a INDEX

Comment: @BerndBuffen I'm looking to insert a transaction while maintaining the user balance to positive, I can ensure he have positive balance by checking if the above query has affected rows therefore he have sufficient balance and the transaction has been logged into the database, can you elaborate?

Comment: I hope my english is good for this. I have seen that you want to insert data, but your select the row. and if this SELECT use a long time the hole Query runs longer and so you have more deadlocks. Faster query -> sorter execution time -> more performance. I will so you a short sample as answer. i cant format it in the comment field.

Comment: @BerndBuffen alright I'll be looking into the answers :)

Answer (score 4):

## General answer

Deadlocks can only occur when you have two or more resources, two or more processes, and the processes lock the resources in different order.

Say, process 1 wants to lock resource A, then B, then C. Process 2 wants to lock B, then A, then C.

This may lead to a dead lock if 1 gets A, then 2 gets B, then 1 waits for B and 2 waits for A - indefinitely.

The solution is, thankfully quite simple: anytime if a process needs to lock two or more resources, it must do so in a "sorted" fashion. In this example,
if process 2 also gets A, then B, then C, a deadlock can never happen.

## Specific answer

In your case, you seem to be locking different table rows within one transaction in more or less random order. Try to find out how to release locks with MySQL and make sure you are only holding as many as you actually need. If you need to hold more than one at a time, try to order your requests in some way.

Hard to tell without knowing more about your code... the first Google hit for "MySQL deadlock" shows some promising stuff though: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/10/28/how-to-deal-with-mysql-deadlocks

Comment: Good Info, but I still can't figure it out, don't know why im so pessimistic about it.

Comment: Check out the link I gave, they seem to have some ways to debug the actual stuff happening in the DB. Does that give you any hints?

Comment: Well I'm going to add some indexes since I didn't have any in all my tables, not sure if it would work. need to find a way to catch exception and retry executing the query :/

Comment: The link provided helped me a great deal to find the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have create a sample table with 2 field. id has primary key

```
MariaDB [who]> DESC mynum;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| num   | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have filled with 100000 records

```
MariaDB [who]> SELECT * FROM mynum LIMIT 10;
+----+----------+
| id | num      |
+----+----------+
|  1 |  0.47083 |
|  2 | 0.670773 |
|  3 | 0.941373 |
|  4 |  0.69455 |
|  5 | 0.648627 |
|  6 | 0.159488 |
|  7 | 0.851557 |
|  8 | 0.779321 |
|  9 | 0.341933 |
| 10 | 0.371704 |
+----+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [who]> SELECT count(*) FROM mynum;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   100000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Now i select row and calculate +10 to the id. You see that he must read ALL rows

```
MariaDB [who]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mynum WHERE id +10 > 20;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mynum | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 100464 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and now i compare the id with a constant. You can see the only reads the row they use and use a index

```
MariaDB [who]> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM mynum WHERE id < 10;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | mynum | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |    9 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I understood what you meant and that's a very good performance boost!